# PHP strtotime function with zero hours and zero minutes give unexpected result

Tags: php, datetime

why it is giving me wrong result when convert the time is `00:00`. its

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
echo  date("G:m", strtotime("00:00"));
echo  date("G:m", strtotime("00:06"));
```

Output:

```
0:06
0:06
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
"G:m"
```

to

```
  "G:i" or "H:i"
```

`m` means month, not minute (hence you see 06 for June).

`G` is for hours 0-23 without preceding zeros

`H` is for hours 00-23 with preceding zeros

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: yeah right , i forget to check on manual. :D thanks dude it works. i will accept your answer when it let me.